# Get array of all unique object values based on property name

Tags: javascript, object

How can I get an array with all the unique values based on a property name?

In my case my object looks like this and I want an array with the unique documentID's.

```
const file = {
  invoice: {
    invoiceID: 1,
    documentID: 5
  },
  reminders: [
    {
      reminderID: 1,
      documentID: 1
    },
    {
      reminderID: 2,
      documentID: 1
    }
  ]
}
```

The result should be an array `[5, 1]` //The unique documentID's are 5 and 1

It doesn't seem like possible to add a property name to the `Object.values()` function.

Comment: What does `[5,1]` even represent/mean?

Comment: You want to remove duplicates from an Array? Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: ow sorry. Deleted a sentence before submiting. The values of the unique documentID's

Comment: You could loop over all properties, check whether the property name matches the name you are looking for, add the value to an array and then finally extract all unique values from this array

Comment: @ChrisSatchell How can I loop over all the properties? `For in` is only looping over the properties in the main object, not the nested objects

Comment: @Thore You'd probably have to check whether the value itself contains nested values

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Set` to get unique documentID.

```js
const file = {
  invoice: {
    invoiceID: 1,
    documentID: 5
  },
  reminders: [
    {
      reminderID: 1,
      documentID: 1
    },
    {
      reminderID: 2,
      documentID: 1
    }
  ],
  payments: {
  documentID : 5
  }
};

var keys = Object.keys(file).map(key=>file[key].map ? file[key].map(i=>i.documentID) : file[key].documentID)

var keysFlattened= [].concat.apply([], keys);

var unique = new Set(keysFlattened);
console.log(Array.from(unique));
```

Comment: Works for this object but it isn't scaleable. What if there are more nested objects? For example conditions or payments.

Comment: I agree but your post didnt mention anything about other keys.

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this that does what you want I think

```
const keepUniqueBy = key => (array, item) => {
  if (array.find(i => item[key] === i[key])) {
    return array;
  } else {
    return [ ...array, item ];
  }
};
```

Then you can simply: `const unique = reminders.reduce(keepUniqueBy('documentID'))`

NB: It's probably low performing, but for small arrays it doesn't matter.